# jQuery Datepicker reopens itself afer picking a date.(In IE)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

On selecting date in datepicker ,its not closing .It keeps on reopening.Helped needed.Thanks.

```
var $viewStartPicker = $('<input type="text" id="viewStartPicker" />');

$viewStartPicker.datepicker().change(function () {
        var d = new Date(this.value);
        if (d == "Invalid Date")
            this.value = "Invalid Date";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? Works fine for me in IE 11.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/z4ry6dtu/

```html
<input type="text" id="viewStartPicker" />
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#viewStartPicker').datepicker().change(function () {
        var d = new Date(this.value);
        if (d == "Invalid Date")
            this.value = "Invalid Date";
    }); 
});
```

Comment: The fiddle not working for me.I am using IE11 and jQuery 1.11.2 @DDan

Comment: Same thing is the JsFiddle? Reopening, or error, or what happens?

Comment: The link had `https` protocol, I took that away, that might have blocked the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me. The idea is: second time, when datepicker calendar is being auto-reopened in IE, e.relatedTarget is body (addNewLightBox is class, assigned to jquery dialog, i use datepicker also in other pages, where this dialog is absent - the problem does not exist there):

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input.datepicker', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.closest('.addNewLightBox').length && $(e.relatedTarget).is('body')) {
        $this.datepicker('destroy');
        $this.closest('.addNewLightBox').focus();
        return;
    };
    $this.datepicker({...});
});
```